# Best way to compare two array of objects in rails

Tags: ruby, comparison

I have two array of objects for example:

```
a1 = [obj1, obj2 , obj3]
a2 = [obj4, obj5, obj6]
```

Each array has different objects of the same class. I want to check whether they have the same attribute value (`obj1.att == obj4.att`) in a single iteration.

`a1.each` will do iteration on a single array. I don't want to use `for` or `while` loop. I want a rails way to do that.

Comment: there is no "rails way" for that, "ruby way" maybe.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess it makes to sense to check that array sizes match before iterating:

```
same_att = a1.size == a2.size && a1.map(&:att) == a2.map(&:att)
```

Same idea, a lazy implementation (only if you have lots of elements in the arrays):

```
same_att = a1.size == a2.size && a1.lazy.zip(a2).all? { |x, y| x.att == y.att }
```

Answer (score 4):

Try following

```
a1.map(&:att) == a2.map(&:att)
```

Edited
    Remember following thing

```
[1,2,3] == [1,2,3]  #true
```

AND

```
[1,2,3] == [2,3,1]  #false
```

Hence it will only returns `true` when `att attribute of obj1, obj4 AND obj2, obj5 AND obj3, obj6 are same.`

Answer (score 0):

```
a1.each {|i| a2.sel­ect {|k|  k.att == i.att }}
```